# Forcing all users to go through SSL with .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ssl

I just installed a SSL certificate on my site, but now I'm facing a problem when I try to force all users to go through secure SSL (HTTPS) instead of  HTTP. I found that the way to to it is using the code below on .htaccess

```
#Force SSL on entire site
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !on [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

So far, it's not working, I get a redirect loop error.

[image]

It's redirecting to the SSL URL, but not working.. without the .htaccess rule it works when i type manually https://example.com

Comment: are there any other rules in .htaccess besides this, or any other .htaccess files in other folders, such as redirects? plus, has the DNS been updated for it and propagated?

Comment: @Fred-ii-, There isn't i just searched on cPanel, and found only 1 .htaccess file on the main directory.

Comment: check your SSL manager, see if there's any messages in there about updating DNS. I just went through something similar lately. the certificate was properly installed too, right? contact your host also.

Comment: I'm using the CloudFlare Flexible SSL Certificate, I guess there's not much I can do about that.

Comment: go through https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us and https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/categories/200276237 if you haven't already. Could be something about that. Or, if you have some PHP with any header redirects, that could also be a possibility; hard to say. I wish I could help you further, but that's about the scope of knowledge I have on this.

Comment: Yes, I have a PHP with header redirects.

https://pastebin.com/V3krgvye

May it cause problems?

Comment: it might. I suggest that you remove all redirects from it (or comment them out) and see what happens. If it still persists, the problem could be on the server itself and/or configurations. If by removing the headers and it works, then try changing your headers to the full URL. I.e.: `header('location: https://example.com/login.php');` or without the "s". However, I'm not betting my bottom dollar on it, but do try what I suggested.

Comment: one thing though; if you remove the .htaccess, does the SSL socket work?

Comment: Yes, it's working without the .htaccess when I type https instead of http on the URL bar, but when I try to force only SSL with .htaccess it doesn't work.

Comment: I'm out of ideas, sorry. Contact the host and see if they can help you out. Maybe someone else will pick up on your question, *cheers*

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea if this will work for you but I do the same thing for my site and this is the code in my `.htaccess` file. I am sure I got it from somewhere here on Stack Overflow.

```
<IFModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
  RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
</IFModule>
```

Comment: I tried it, and it didn't work for me, still the same problem, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Should work fine...