# SSL Forcing through .htaccess results in redirect loop on wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, ssl

I'm trying to force SSL on my Wordpress site. I've followed every step I've found on the internet (force_ssl_admin, set site to https://), but when changing the .htaccess file to what it should be to force ssl I'm stuck on a redirect loop. I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32707638/forcing-all-users-to-go-through-ssl-with-htaccess) where someone has the same issue but it appears unresolved. I'm not sure if my issue is entirely the same so that's why I'd like to make a post about my issue.

When I add this .htaccess:

```
SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-Proto https HTTPS
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite.be [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mysite.be [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mysite.be/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

I'm stuck at a redirect loop. (Of course `my site` is changed to my domain) Going back to this .htaccess:

```
SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-Proto https HTTPS
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Allows me to get back on my wp-pages. Maybe a little sidenote: My site itself still works with the redirect loop, only the admin pages are in a redirect loop.

sidenote: I've tried the plugin `simple-ssl` before, this worked to force the ssl but it also made sure I lost the facebook http likes and comments so I'd prefer to not use this plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing the `RewriteCond` to prevent code from being executed when it's already https in a different way was the fix for me. I tried a lot of ways to check if the url was https or not with `%{HTTPS} !on` or `%{HTTPS} off`, but nothing worked. However, [this comment](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/205963/143327) helped me out.

The answer for me was rewriting the condition:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
```

eventually my .htaccess file is just:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mysite.be/$1 [R,L]
```